# Display:box does not work well on Safari 6

Tags: css

SASS

```
> .pure-g > div[class^="pure-u"] {
    //height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

    &.actions{

        // display: -webkit-box;
        // // -moz-box-pack: center;
        // -webkit-box-align: center;
        /* Firefox */
        display: -moz-box;
        // -moz-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;

        /* IE */
        display: -ms-box;
        // -ms-box-pack: center;
        -ms-box-align: center;

         /* Native CSS */
        display: box;
        // box-pack: center;
        box-align: center;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="pure-u-1-3 l-padding actions">
<input type="submit" class="pure-button btn-submit" value="Upload"/>
</div>
```

Use purecss.io and custom css. The button float on left side when it should stay in action div on right aligned to middle. tried different way but only safari 6 needs webkit-box to work. but not work well for latest chrome browser. sigh.

any help appreciated

Update - Images
[image: Chrome]

This is chrome -- not vertically middle.

[image: Firefox]

This is FF - vertically middle

Answer (score 0):

do it this way, might help!!

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

here is a good read about it : [**Flexbox**](http://html5please.com/#flexbox)

**EDIT**

if alignment is an issue, why don't you use `display:table-cell;` instead of flex box, it more widely supported.

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6ct4/)

[**check compatibility here**](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable)

Comment: does it support Safari 6?

Comment: @kittymeows : it should, havent tested on safari 6, if it doesn't, then for browser support do as per http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ ...and yeah any safari is supported!! :)

Comment: ok tried to follow but it doesn't help to make the button input to be vertically aligned to middle. firefox it shows middle align.

Comment: @kittymeows : can you give me your fiddle with the code??

Comment: er.. the templates are dynamic so it wouldn't be contained in straight box. so u wont see in jsfiddle :( http://jsfiddle.net/kittymeow/cJ3WS/

Comment: provide a snapshot then explaining what is not working and what u expect it to look like!! :)

Comment: upload the snapshot examples.

Comment: @kittymeows Safari 6 partially supports flexbox: See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: @kittymeows : added an edit in answer, please check!

Comment: @NoobEditor - thanks and I have tried table and table-cell before. Anyway, I have already corrected the flexbox issue. Tested on all browsers - seem that it is working ok. thanks for your help

Comment: @kittymeows : i'll suggest u to post your answer here and mark it accepted...may help some future visitor!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor - post answer above?